# Filter function in DAX

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I hope someone can help me.
I'm struggling with a DAX related question. I want to add a calculated column to index my cashflow with the index % from previous years.

I have a many-to-one relation. 
One table with containing cashflows in different years (column= year + cashflow). I want to index the cashflows with the inflation % in another table.
The other tablad contains column like year and index %.

I'm not very experienced with DAX, but I tried the following:

cashflow_index = calculate( PRODUCT( B[index %]) ; filter ( B ; B[year] <= A[year]))

But i get an error. Can somebody help me to index the cashflows.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add a screenshot of your data as well

Comment: To increase chances of receiving an answer, I suggest you to adopt the standard template: 1) Context, 2) Problem, 3) Example with a table, 4) Expected results in the table of (3) Example.